# Add New line between 2 variables in PHPspreadsheet in PHP

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I have created a link to export data in excel from database using the following code

`$sheet->setCellValue('A1', $row['address_line_1'] . '\n' . $row['address_line_2']);`

After executing the code the excel generated as follows

```
Delhi\nIndia
```

Not as

```
Delhi
India
```

Comment: It is `"\n"`, note the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', "Delhi\nIndia");
$sheet->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```